# VR View Web and iOS

Tags: google-vr, 360-virtual-reality

In the VRView web documentation there is the following statement in the known issues section;

360° images will have incorrect orientation in iOS Safari if you explicitly declare your iframe (instead of using the JavaScript API) and the code and images are hosted on different servers.

However as far as I am aware I am not using the iFrame mode of operation, but instead using the .JS method in the examples, however the video is still at 90 degrees when the phone is put into VR Mode....  I can sort of live with the image not quite in full screen mode, but not with the orientation.

Alternatively is there a way to 'self-host' the VR View package, on a Hosting platform, so that the iFrame method of calling the video works?

`<iframe src="/vrview/src/embed?video=injected1.mp4&is_stereo=false"></iframe>`

Doesnt work as it says Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /vrview/src/embed/ on this server.

Any help gretefully received

Comment: Could you share a link on the "VRView web documentation". I cannot find it anywhere

Comment: Simple google search for ‘google vr view web’.  https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/web/vrview-web

Comment: Next time please mention you're talking about a component from Google framework. A title with iOS was confusing in this case